# Android CardView Alpha

Tags: android, alpha, material-design, android-cardview

Is there any way to change the alpha of CardView in android. Whatever I try doesn't work. I tried this and even tried changing the alpha of a framelayout surrounding it but nothing works.

```
Footer.findViewById(R.id.base).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(Footer.findViewById(R.id.base)).cancel();
                ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(Footer.findViewById(R.id.base)).alpha(1f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                        Footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete a card and meanwhile its getting deleted you are gradually fading it out?

Comment: K..i have added my answer below

Comment: Did the code posted below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First in the `anim` folder add the below code, the code has 2 parts one is to move the card from left to right and the second part to fade it out in that process.

**move_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="400"
           android:toAlpha="0.0"/>
</set>
```

In the java code invoke `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()` as below

```
cardview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.move_right));
```

This will cause the cardview to move from left to right and gradually fade doing so.